# qt event listener not registering

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Can anyone tell me why my event listener is not registering in `qt`? It might be a problem with the `MainWindow` itself but I've been struggling to find the solution. I have another solution that I've been following and it seems to me this is how the `keylistener`is implemented but it's not working in this example. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

C++ code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    QPushButton * singleButton = new QPushButton("Single Player", this);
    connect(singleButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onSingleButtonClicked()));
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &view, SLOT(advance()));
    timer.start(1000 / 33);

}

void MainWindow::onSingleButtonClicked(void)
{

view.setSceneRect(-250, -250, 500, 500);

view.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);
pair = new Pair(300, 300);
QGraphicsRectItem * border = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRect(-150, -150, 300, 400));
border->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
border->setBrush(Qt::white);
view.addItem(border);
view.addItem(pair->getCentrePiece());
view.addItem(pair->getOuterPiece());


board = new QGraphicsView(&view);
board->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
board->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::yellow);

board->setWindowTitle(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(QGraphicsView, "Game"));
//#if defined(Q_WS_S60) || defined(Q_WS_MAEMO_5) || defined(Q_WS_SIMULATOR)
//    board->showMaximized();
//#else

board->show();
board->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
board->update();
//#endif
}



void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    abort();

}
```

Header file code:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include "pair.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);


protected:

      void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene view;
    Pair * pair;
    QVBoxLayout * vlayout;
    QGraphicsView * board;
    QTimer timer;

    private slots:
        void onSingleButtonClicked();
    };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: What is the abort() and what do you expect, something should happen when user press key?

Comment: Just to know if the code runs the program will exit, which it doesnt

Comment: First of all it will work when your mainwindow has focus, second: add something like `qDebug("work!");` inside pressEvent, can you see work! when mainwindow has focus and you press some button?

Comment: so two screens are created. one is created initially and one is cretaed after hitting start. I need the new window, which is a graphicsScene to request the focus I presume?

Comment: I miaunderstood something. There are mainWindow and board. KeyEvent in board and keyEvent in MainWindow are different(!) events. Which of these events you want catch? Kry pressing in mainwindow or in board?

Comment: Well main window has a start button. when you hit start button the 'board'is initilized. I want the focus to be on the board but it remains on the main window

Comment: Then use this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus but you will not be able to catch event from board because your keyPressEvent listem onlybasic mainwindow